# I appear to be connected to the internet, but internet doesn't work

Tags: windows-vista, wireless-networking, internet

I've read a few posts about this problem before but it was either a slightly different problem than mine or people suggested what the problem could be, not a solution.

I am running Windows Vista 64bit (the worst possible combination, I know) on a HP HDX 16 laptop. It appears to be connected to the network, and the internet, but when I try to browse the web my browser complains that all pages "are not available", and any software I try to update, doesn't.

ipconfig says nothing is connected, though it shows I have an IP address.

I tried ipconfig/release+renew but it didn't work. After that I tried netsh winsock reset, rebooted the laptop and still nothing.

What course of action can I take now?

Comment: What do you mean `ipconfig` says nothing is connected?  From CMD, can you ping IP addresses?  Try `ping 209.85.146.99`, or just paste `209.85.146.99` into a browser address bar.  If you get Google.com, it's a DNS problem.

Comment: I do get Google.com if I do that. So what does "DNS problem" mean? What should I do to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set Google's DNS servers, open a CMD Prompt and paste these lines in, one at a time:

```
netsh int ipv4 add dnsservers "Local Area Connection" 8.8.8.8 index=1
netsh int ipv4 add dnsservers "Local Area Connection" 8.8.4.4 index=2
```

For wifi, try:

```
netsh int ipv4 add dnsservers "Wireless Network Connection" 8.8.8.8 index=1
netsh int ipv4 add dnsservers "Wireless Network Connection" 8.8.4.4 index=2
```

This is assuming that the network adaptors are using the default names, which you can find on the Networking tab of Task Manager.

[For the GUI method, try this.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Change-TCP-IP-settings)  Step 6 is the relevant part.

Comment: I am using WiFi, yes, sorry I forgot to mention.

Comment: It gives me the error "The following command was not found: [what you told me to type]" for both commands. If I do netsh/? in the cmd the "add" command is there, which makes it more confusing. My version of windows is localized, Greek. would it make a difference for the network names?

Comment: @OddCore: I don't know why that is happening.  Just do it the GUI way then.  You need to add the two IP address from above into the TCP/IP settings:  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Change-TCP-IP-settings

Comment: @OddCore - You probably have to run the cmd prompt as administrator. Right click on the shortcut and select "Run as administrator"

Comment: @OddCore: Yes, I think the adaptor names will be different in Greek Windows.  You will find them on the Networking tab of Task manager.

Comment: So, just to make sure, I go into ipv4's properties, then "advanced", then on the DNS tab I add 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 in the second window down, not the first? I would mention what the windows say to make it easier for you, but Greek computer terminology makes no sense. Ever.

Comment: @OddCore:  No, do not go to `Advanced`.  Just add the addresses to the bottom part of the `General` tab where the `Advanced` button is.

Comment: So, 8.8.8.8 in Preferred and 8.8.4.4 in Alternate? I'm sorry if I come across as thick but I want to make sure I don't do anything irreversible.

Comment: @OddCore: Either way is fine.  I was trying to avoid this confusing with the command-line method.

Comment: Excellent, thank you, it works now. If you can be asked, would you mind explaining roughly what I just did? And will I have a problem with this when I try to connect to a different network, say, my university houses' network, which is abroad?

Comment: @OddCore: Google's DNS servers are available from anywhere in the world, as far as I know, so you should not have any problems with that.  Your computer needs to ask DNS servers to get the IP addresses for any domain names.  Domain names only exist to make it easier for humans to remember, but computers need to ask DNS servers to translate them into IP addresses.

Comment: I see. Well, thank you for your help, I hope the gratitude of everyone you have helped including me is enough to keep you active on here. Take care.