# It appears you are connected to the Internet, but you might want to try to reconnect to the Internet

Tags: windows, networking, internet-explorer

I'm getting an error from internet Explorer that makes no obvious sense to me. The error is *"It appears you are connected to the Internet, but you might want to try to reconnect to the Internet."*

[image]

Noe of the information under *More Information* was helpful, like DNS is broken or there's no internet connection. In fact, I can ping named hosts, like `www.google.com` and `notepad-plus-plus.org`.

I think this is a related question: [I appear to be connected to the internet, but internet doesn't work](https://superuser.com/q/269963), but its not helpful either. In my case, I have a wired connection and can ping outside hosts.

I found a few unhelpful posts when searching Microsoft's site for the error message, like "Have you tried installing AV and making sure you don't have malware".

What, exactly, is this message telling me? And how do I work around it?

Comment: I dont know if you already found [this link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/internet-works-but-not-internet-explorer/d31b05a0-e922-41b3-a2f4-139e00962ca0http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/internet-works-but-not-internet-explorer/d31b05a0-e922-41b3-a2f4-139e00962ca0?auth=1 "this link" "this link") or not but maybe it has the answers.

Comment: Try resetting Windows Firewall to its default settings. Try flushing the DNS cache: cmd: `ipconfig /flushdns`.